# assigning a hyperlink to an image with javascript in the example

Tags: javascript, html, popup, lightcase.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var imgURLs = [
    'https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
     "https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_frontpage_en-US_s_f_p_205x58_frontpage_2x.png"
  ];
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgURLs.length);
  var imgURL = imgURLs[randomIndex];

  
  
  setTimeout(function(){
      lightcase.start({
        href: imgURL,
        // more options like width, height, etc.
      });
   },1000); // 1000 to load it after 1 second from page load
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightcase/2.5.0/css/lightcase.css'>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->



<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightcase/2.5.0/js/lightcase.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[example](https://codepen.io/srga/pen/bMmrOR)

I will add a popup to my website as in the example, but I want to add hyperlinks to the images opened in the js code.
For example, when the google image opens, when I click on the image, I want to go to the google.com web page. Please help.

```
I haven't tried yet
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute to set the attributes.

Some things to do:

- Create a `<a>` element using JavaScript.
- Create a `<img>` element using JavaScript.
- Append the `<img>` element to `<a>` as a child using `appendChild()`
- Use JS `document.getElementbyID()` and use
  `ELEMENT.setAttribute(NAMEOFATTRIBUTE,  value)` to set the `href` of the `<a>` element.
- Use JS `document.getElementbyID()` and use
  `ELEMENT.setAttribute(NAMEOFATTRIBUTE, value)` to set the `src` of the `<img>` element.

Comment: Can you edit the js in the my example to create hyperlinks to the dropdown images?

Comment: I did. That's step 1, 3, and 4.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do:

- Create a popup container element
- Create a hyperlink and set the appropriate attributes
- Append the hyperlink to the container as a child
- Create an image element and set the appropriate attributes
- Append the image to the hyperlink as a child

What this will look like in your JavaScript:

```js
// Create the container element
let container = document.createElement('div');
// Add your class styles
container.classList.add('popup-container');
// Create the link element
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.src = 'https://example.com';
// Create the image element
let image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = './path/to/image.png';
// Add to DOM
document.body.appendChild(container);
container.appendChild(link);
link.appendChild(image);
```

If you are planning on having multiple popups, you should create a `Popup` class for this and just use `new Popup()` wherever you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I couldn't understand. Can you update and share the sample codes?

Comment: @dede1907 what specifically do you want me to update?

Comment: I want you to add links to images by editing the js code that works in the example

Comment: @dede1907 That is what this answer does. It creates a link and puts an image in the link, creating a linked image. I will not write your code for you. I have given you the information you need. It is up to you to implement it.